# Show that this integral is continuous (review)

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-integral

here is the problem :

We work in $([0,\infty[,B(\mathbb{R}),\nu_1)$.
Let $f\in \mathcal{L^1}$, and for $x\ge0$, let :

\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_0^{x}f(t)\,dt\\
\end{align}

Show that F is continuous.

Here's my attempt :
Let $h(x,t):=f(t)*1_{[0,x]}(t)$, we're gonna apply the theorem of continuity for integrals with parameters :

- $h(x,.)$ is measurable
- For $x\ge0$, $f$ is continuous because constant, now let's show that $1_{[0,x]}(t)$ is continuous.

Let $t\ge0$, $(x_n)_n$ a real number sequence that convergences toward $x$, then for t in $[0,x_n]$, we have that when $n$ goes to infinity, $t$ ends up in $[0,x]$, i.e the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $1_{[0,x_n]}(t)$ is $1=1_{[0,x]}(t)$

We repeat the same step when $t>x_n$.

$1_{[0,x]}(t)$ is thus continuous.

- Finally we have that : $\rvert f \lvert \ge \rvert h \lvert$

We apply the theorem, which gives us F continuous. My only problem is this one : in the exercise, we are asked to use the almost everywhere variation of this theorem, yet I've done it without, which means that there must be something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated

Edit :
As pointed out under, $1_{[0,x]}(t)=1_{[t,\infty](x)}$, which is continuous almost everywhere (except on ${t}$, who is $\nu_1$-negligeable). And that's how we use the a.e theorem.

I still don't know why $1_{[0,x]}(t)$ is continuous, my proof looks legit

Comment: What's the value of $F(y) - F(x)$? By the way, for $t$ fixed, $\mathbb{1}_{[0, \cdot]}(t)$ is not continuous, because it is the function $x \mapsto \mathbb{1}_{[t, +\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: What's wrong with the way I showed that $1_{[0,]x}(t)$ is continuous ? What's implied is that it's the two variable function $g(x,t):=1_{[0,]x}(t)$, I feel like it works. As for the value of $F(y)-F(x)$, Im not sure what you mean. Is that a hint of some sort ?